# How to Write Javascript Sweet Alert from Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, sweetalert

my controller

```
$delete = ModelDelete::find($id);
    if ($delete->delete()) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Deleted!');
    }
```

Currently this is my view

```
@section('js')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
@if (session('alert'))
    swal({{ session('alert') }});
@endif
</script>
@endsection
```

but that didn't happen anything :(
is there something wrong with my coding? sorry I'm new to trying this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it going inside the `if` statement?, have you seen if the console throws any error?

I would suggest you surround with `"` your brackets statement like this:

`swal("{{ session('alert') }}");`

Answer (score 0):

Correct this in your code:

```
<script>
@if (session('alert'))
    swal("{{ session('alert') }}");
@endif
</script>
```

It works. Thanks